# Generating a unique id of std::string

Tags: c++

I want to generate any limited std::string size unique id (i.e of size 6) in 32 bit application. what would be the best and quick way to do this?

Comment: What sort of id? Numeric? And how unique? To your application, the session, the  machine, the world?

Comment: It can have any ASCII character which is unique enough so i don't get the same id again. it can be of any size from 1 to 8 for use in my application.

Comment: In that case, what is wrong with a the obvious sequence 1,2,3,....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look up hashing of strings, e.g. the [Jenkins hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_hash_function).

But you will *never* get unique hashes, because strings can be much longer than your size 6, and the [Pigoenhole lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) shows trivially that hashes *must* collide as a a consequence.

Answer (score 1):

Very difficult to tell from your question what you are asking, but the following generates strings in the sequence "1", "2", "3":

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::string GetUniqueId() {
   static int n = 1;
   std::ostringstream os;
   os << n++;
   return os.str();
}
```

Comment: I'm saving the data with unique IDs in a file, If i were to use 1.. 2.. 3.. sequence then how would i know if the ID was already given to some data the next time i load the file?
I guess it would be better if I generate the id's from each unique data that may have ID's.

Comment: Why didn't you state that in your original question? The quality of the answers you get here is directly proportional to the clarity and detail of your question.

Comment: Note that this method is not thread safe. At least the `static` variable would need to be protected against concurrent access.